# Eclipse error "GCC and G++ not found"

Tags: c

I know this has been asked before, but I simply cannot get any of the solutions to work for me. I'm trying to finish my homework for my C class, but I can't compile. I have cygwin, edited both my eclipse and environment PATHs to include cygwin, and it just won't work. Help?

Comment: are you talking about Eclipse or the Eclipse CDT, aka the plugin that you are supposed to use when programming in C and C++ ? Under which platform ?

Comment: Not as ninja edit as I thought: I had said something about not knowing about CDT.

Comment: you can download CDT either as a separate plugin http://eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php or you can pick a bundle of Eclipse for C/C++ developers http://eclipse.org/downloads/

Comment: I guess I had downloaded the bundle for C/C++, so I already have the plugin, but the issue still remains.

Comment: http://www.badprog.com/c-eclipse-installation-of-c-c-development-tools-cdt-and-cygwin-for-windows and since you still have to specify your OS I'm assuming it's Windows.

Comment: @user2485710: The OP has Cygwin, which runs only on Windows.